# Excluding the time in a "date/time" parameter for SSRS reports

Tags: ssrs-2008, reporting-services

In my SSRS report, I wanted to allow the users to specify a date (that would be used to filter the data on a report).  When I did this, the parameter also includes the time.  Is it possible to just allow the user to select a date, without showing the time?  Can I also give it a default value of the current date?

The steps that I had already applied to the report parameter:

1. Set the parameter to "date / time" data type.
2. Set the default value of this parameter to be `=Now`.

When I did this, the report parameter would show me:

```
23/04/2013 00:31:22
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Instead of using `=Now()` you can use `=Today()` which provides current date without time .If you are getting data from DB then you can

```
=Format(Fields!YourDateColumn.Value,"dd/MM/yyyy")
```

Check this [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157328%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) article for using expressions and formatting the date time column

Comment: Note that the parameter type is "date/time" so if you only specify a date as the default, the parameter value will still include a time component of 00:00:00. This can be important if you then use the parameter value to compare to a SQL Server DATETIME data type.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this helps. My way of accomplishing this is:

```
=DateSerial(Year(Now), Month(Now), Day(Now))
```

[image: SSRS Default Date Param]

Thank You,

Answer (score 1):

[image]Depends on type of IDE you use, you may NOT be able to use some of those suggested methods. This always work for me: Set parameter type=TEXT instead of Date/Time, then on query convert your date as follow: `SELECT Value=Convert(varchar(20),payperiod,101`)