# Remove Time From SSRS Date Parameter

Tags: t-sql, reporting-services, parameters, casting

> I want to remove the time from my Parameter Selection Dropdown, NOT a cell referencing the parameter

I have a simple parameter `weekEndingDate` which is fed by my `dataset`

```
SELECT TOP (8) Convert(Date,FullDate, 101) AS FullDate
FROM DimDate
WHERE (DayNameOfWeek = 'Friday') AND (CAST(FullDate AS Date) < CAST(GETDATE() AS Date))
ORDER BY FullDate DESC
```

I have also tried

```
SELECT TOP (8) CAST(FullDate as Date) AS FullDate
FROM DimDate
WHERE (DayNameOfWeek = 'Friday') AND (CAST(FullDate AS Date) < CAST(GETDATE() AS Date))
ORDER BY FullDate DESC
```

> The issue is that the parameter options still display time.

If I execute the query in Query Designer I get basically correct output (Convert is giving me `m/dd/yyyy`, instead of `mm/dd/yyyy`) and this is true for cast and convert, but the parameter drop down still has time, and if I put the parameter into a cell, it also has the time

> I have deleted the .data files
>
> I have deleted and recreated the parameter, but did not deploy or rebuild or anything WITHOUT the parameter, I deleted and immediately recreated then hit Preview
>
> I have tried both CAST and CONVERT
>
> I have tried Previewing, Running, and Deploying the report

In all cases the time remains and I am dumbfounded, all help appreciated, and I'm happy to clarify anything

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16158469/excluding-the-time-in-a-date-time-parameter-for-ssrs-reports

Comment: Instead of putting in an all-caps "this isn't a duplicate", try explaining why your situation is distinct from the linked question, and why the solution there doesn't apply.

Comment: Have you tried setting your Parameter Data Type to Text instead of Date/Time?

Comment: @Beofett, you are right, I rephrased the post to prevent future confusion

Comment: @Molleyc, that was a great idea! it didn't quite do it, but I recast the formatted date as varchar and that worked! please rephrase the suggestion as an answer and I will award you the correct response

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try setting your Parameter Data Type to Text instead of Date/Time.

Also changing the dataset to return varchar was necessary

Final dataset code:

```
SELECT TOP (8) CAST(CONVERT(Date, FullDate, 101)as VARCHAR) AS FullDate
FROM DimDate
WHERE (DayNameOfWeek = 'Friday') AND (CAST(FullDate AS Date) < CAST(GETDATE() AS Date))
ORDER BY FullDate DESC
```

Comment: On its own this is a poor workaround, considering that the whole reason for using `date` columns is to leverage their semantics, e.g. being easily comparable (without `cast`ing back) to given start/end dates, etc. If SSRS gives us no option than to use the `varchar` kludge, you sdould return _two_ columns, one `cast`ed to text, and use the latter as the _label_ - but keep the parameter value as a proper date with semantics.

Comment: @underscore_d - that would make perfect sense if the question was about returning the actual data for display in a column on the report. It was simply about returning dates for selection from a parameter list.

Answer (score 0):

Sourced from: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/95d23f74-d7d3-41e1-8538-dbeff6e65ee2/ssrs-2008-r2-parameter-datetime-how-to-hide-time

1. Open your report in SQL Server Business Intelligence Development Studio or Report Builder3.0.
2. Click the Design tab, right-click the textbox where you will display the @Time parameter, select expression.
3. Clear the expression dialog box, then type in:
   =FormatDateTime(Parameters!Timer.Value, DateFormat.ShortDate) or =FormatDateTime(Parameters!Timer.Value,2).

Comment: This would work, but I want the time removed from the Parameter Selection list, not a specific cell

Answer (score 0):

the accepted answer does not provide a complete solution, since it changes the data type instead of the format of the parameter. Another solution, which I think has less drastic side effects is to make sure that you set a default date value, and format this to be a date rather than a date time, for instance:

```
=CDATE(FORMAT(DATEADD(DateInterval.Day,-30,Globals!ExecutionTime),"dd/MM/yyyy"))
```

This will result in the default date *and subsequently selected dates from the datepicker* to be displayed in a date only format, while still being a date. This is the method I use.